# Automatic lettrine to input file

Tags: input, lettrine

I'm learning LaTex but have a strong programming background. My document consist of several `.tex` files I will `\input` at entry `.tex` file. I would like to add a lettrine to every one of them, but would rather not edit the separate `.tex` files. Instead, I would love if I could, somehow, get the first word of the file, then get the first letter of that first word, and then dynamically insert the `lettrine{H}{eya}` and append the rest of the file.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

In addition, I'm using a new command to perform certain operations before actually inputting the file, so the actual call to `\input` is done using a command argument, like this `\input{#2}`. The only answers solves my problem when calling input outside other command, but not inside the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define

```
\def\dolettrine #1#2 {\lettrine{#1}{#2} }
```

and use

```
\expandafter \dolettrine \input file.tex
```

But, if you are using LaTeX then there are complications, because `\input` TeX primitive is redefined. So, you can do something like this:

```
\catcode`\@=11
\expandafter \dolettrine \@@input file.tex
```

Comment: `\def\dolettrine #1#2 {\lettrine{#1}{#2} }` passes only the first two letters, and not the first letter and then the rest of the word.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña No. `#1` is the first letter and `#2` is the rest of the first word. Note that `#1` is undelimited parameter and `#2` is delimited parameter with space delimiter. Note the space after `#2` declaration.

Comment: In addition, when using inside a `\newcommand`, it's advised to enclose the definition in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, to make it work seamlessly. @wipet, please consider adding your comments regarding this, for the sake of completion.