# How to make the First Word of every Chapter's First textgraph be cap-droped automatically?

Tags: lettrine, drop-cap

MWE:

```
% !tex=pdflatex
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,lettrine}

\begin{document}
% NOTE1: There have text between Chapter and Section, I just want to the first word be dropcaped like below.
\chapter{Week1}
\lettrine{W}{ith} a drop cap, the initial sits
within the margins and runs several lines deep into the paragraph, pushing some
normal-sized text off these lines.
\section{Day1 of Week1}
\lipsum[1]  
Chapter one end. 

% NOTE2: There have NOT any text between Chapter and Section, but I just want to the first word be drop-caped like below.
\chapter{Week2}
\section{Day1 of Week2}
\lettrine{L}{orem} \lipsum[1]  

% NOTE3: How to do this work like above(just let the first word be drop-caped in every chapter) 
% through the whole book automatically?
\chapter{Week3}
\lipsum[1]  

\end{document}
```

What I can do are showed as NOTE1 and NOTE2. I just want to find a best solution to do this work automatically(NOTE3).

Comment: Maybe your question would sound better that way: "Automating lettrine after \chapter command"

Comment: How many chapters do you have? This required automation seems like a large investment for minimal reward if you can just edit (say) 10 locations and place a `\lettrine` there, especially if there's not always a consistent way in which you present what could follow `\chapter`... just saying.

Answer (score 2):

The solution below, which is actually a half solution and maybe even a brute solution, is inspired by this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290567/231952. It requires three conditions. 1) There must not be empty lines after `\chapter` and 2) the text after `\chapter` must not start with a `\`; 3) The standard `book` class is used:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\dolettrine #1#2 { \lettrine{#1}{#2} }    
\makeatletter
  \apptocmd{\@chapter}{\dolettrine}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\chapter{Dolor sit}
%
Dolor sit amet lorem ipsum

\chapter{Dolor magnum}
% In this case it does not work correctly
\textit{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

**Edit.**

The first limitation can be removed with:

```
\apptocmd\@makechapterhead{\endlinechar=32}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@afterheading}{\endlinechar=13}{}{}
```

The solution is inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16462/231952. The first command appends `\endlinechar=32` to `\@makechapterhead`,  so that the end of lines are replaced by a space. The second command restore the default value `13`.

For the starred variant of `\chapter` we need this too:

```
\apptocmd{\@schapter}{\dolettrine}{}{}
\apptocmd\@makeschapterhead{\endlinechar=32}{}{}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for the situation you mentioned. Maybe have some more perfact method to remove these limitations.

Comment: I edited my answer including a workaround to exclude the first limitation. I added also a third condition: `book` class is required

Comment: Thanks! I try add them but it does not work for the NOTE2 and NOTE3.

Comment: It is correct. NOTE2 and NOTE3 start with a ` \ ` after `\chapter` (\section and \lipsum respectively). This violates the second condition. The same job should also be done for the `\section` command too, but it becomes difficult if there are chapters that start with plain text and others that start with a `\section`

Comment: OK, I see. NOTE2 and NOTE3 make things a little complex. Maybe `scoop up paragraphs` can do this? I don't know.

Comment: Io cannot figure out what you mean by "scoop up paragraphs". Again, the solution I gave requires that there is plain text immediately after `\chapter {}`.